# Getting Invalid label error in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I am getting Invalid label error in firefox while receiving some json content from another domain. My JS code is :

```
$.getJSON('http://www.upsidelearning.com/blog/blogapp/getBlogDetails.php?getBlogsList=1&jsoncallback=?', function(data){
     alert("Success");
      });
```

And In chrome error console following error received :

```
(Warning)Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
(Error) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

EDIT : My response json is :

```
{"data":[{"title":"How Long Does It Take To Develop An Hour Of Elearning?","publishDate":"15 September 2011","author":"Abhijit Kadle","permalink":"http:\/\/www.upsidelearning.com\/blog\/index.php\/2011\/09\/15\/how-long-does-it-take-to-develop-an-hour-of-elearning\/","thumbnail":"http:\/\/www.upsidelearning.com\/blog\/blogapp\/images\/blogpost-icon.png","id":9197}]}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please post the response JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting Invalid label error in firefox while receiving some json content from another domain.

Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction it is not allowed to send AJAX requests to different domains. There are a couple of workarounds:

1. Use JSONP. There is a specific section about it in the [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) documentation. Works only if the remote domain supports it. So for example instead of:

   ```
   {"data":[{"title":"How Long Does It Take To Develop An Hour Of Elearning?","publishDate":"15 September 2011","author":"Abhijit Kadle","permalink":"http:\/\/www.upsidelearning.com\/blog\/index.php\/2011\/09\/15\/how-long-does-it-take-to-develop-an-hour-of-elearning\/","thumbnail":"http:\/\/www.upsidelearning.com\/blog\/blogapp\/images\/blogpost-icon.png","id":9197}]}
   ```

   the remote domain must be able to return:

   ```
   callback({"data":[{"title":"How Long Does It Take To Develop An Hour Of Elearning?","publishDate":"15 September 2011","author":"Abhijit Kadle","permalink":"http:\/\/www.upsidelearning.com\/blog\/index.php\/2011\/09\/15\/how-long-does-it-take-to-develop-an-hour-of-elearning\/","thumbnail":"http:\/\/www.upsidelearning.com\/blog\/blogapp\/images\/blogpost-icon.png","id":9197}]})
   ```

   where the client could set the `callback` name.
2. If JSONP is not an option you could write a server side script on your domain that will act as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain and then send the AJAX request to your script.

---

UPDATE:

After the numerous comments it seems that you are trying to use YQL. Here's a [full working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4AN2X/):

```
$.get('http://www.upsidelearning.com/blog/blogapp/getBlogDetails.php?getCategories=1&callback=?', function(result) {
    // you could parse the JSON like this:
    // var json = $.parseJSON(($(result.responseText).filter('p').text()));
    // alert(json.data[0].id);

    alert("Success");
});
```

Notice that you should use `$.get` and not `$.getJSON`.

Comment: But i am receiving my json data on client side but while firefox and chrome showing me error.

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao, as I said if you want to achieve cross domain AJAX calls you need either JSONP (see in my answer how the response from the server should look like) or use a bridge script.

Comment: @Darin..I know JSONP very well ... but i want to know the solution on the JSON that am receiving (without setting callback name on JSON string)

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao, if you understand JSONP, then you should also understand that the server must return JSONP response, not JSON which is what it currently does. For example navigate to the following url: http://www.upsidelearning.com/blog/blogapp/getBlogDetails.php?getBlogsList=1&jsoncallback=abc You see the response? It's JSON, not JSONP so this won't work. I repeat once again: if you want to achieve cross domain AJAX calls you have 2 possibilities: JSONP or a server side bridge. Apparently the remote server doesn't support JSONP so you are left with option 2.

Comment: @Darin..Thanks for your time..but i don't want to change the server side code..bcoz it is already used in many applications, so it is hard to change JSON..Is this possible without changing server side code ?

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao, yes it is possible: you would write a server side bridge on your domain (the domain that executes this javascript) which will send an HTTP request to the remote domain to fetch the JSON and return this JSON to the client. Then on javascript you will simply send an AJAX request to this new script: `$.getJSON('/mybridge', ...);`

Comment: @Darin...Thanks again..I know it is possible through bridge..But is it possible without bridge...means making some changes on client side ?

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao, NO, it is not possible. Think of it that way: the same origin policy restriction was introduced in browsers on purpose and if it was so easy to circumvent it, this policy wouldn't exist on the first place.

Comment: @Darin..then how this works http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: @TusharAhirrao, it uses YQL, and the request is sent to the Yahoo servers which in turn support JSONP, their server side script serves as a bridge to the remote domain and returns the result wrapped in a JSONP response. The other approach uses Flash but this of course requires that you have control of the remote domain in order to put the `crossdomain.xml` file in its root.

Comment: @Darin..I tried this http://jsbin.com/ukotol/3/edit#javascript,html  ...added flavor of cross-domain script from http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide but this is also not working

Comment: @TusharAhirrao, there is no trace of JSONP when I request: `http://www.upsidelearning.com/blog/blogapp/getBlogDetails.php?getCategories=1&callback=abc`. So it is not surprising that it doesn't work. You are trying to directly access this url and this url doesn't support JSONP. I think you are missing the whole point of my answer and how JSONP is required for cross domain AJAX.

Comment: @Darin..but am using this script http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide...

Comment: @TusharAhirrao, which script are you using? That's an article that you have linked to containing different approaches. One of the approaches is to use YQL.

Comment: @Tushar Ahirrao, see my updated answer. You should use `$.get` and not `$.getJSON` if you go the YQL route.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the server side script isn't prefixing any callback. You need to get that fixed. It's returning plain `JSON` which cannot be executed without passing it into a function or callback.

Comment: Is there any other solution to this problem.. means by setting datatype property

Comment: No. The server isn't sending a well formatted JSONP response. Maybe it doesn't support JSONP?

Comment: @Sahil..then how this is working?...http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide